# Is there a metadata table that shows information other than the column name/id/data type for a partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery

[big query table metadata as seen on the UI console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZWDI.png)

Is there an info schema table or equivalent that shows the following metadata information about a partitioned table :

Partition range end,
Partition range interval,
Partition range start,
Partitioned by  (eg day, hour, month, year)

I can see them in the console UI when clicking on the details tab on the table, but cannot find which if any info schema tables contain them. I've looked in all the listed ones from the google site but cannot se them in there:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-intro

Is there a table in BQ this is contained that's accessible?

At the moment the only way I can find to determine whether a table that's been date partitioned for example by month/day is to look at the length of the partition_id for each partition and determine it that way. It would be more useful/reliable if I could see the information as it's displayed on the console, where it shows partitioned by DAY or MONTH or YEAR etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select *
from `your-project.your_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` tbl
where regexp_contains(lower(ddl), 'partition by')
```

Below are fields available to choose from

[image]

Comment: I hadn't thought of looking in the ddl of the table creation.  I was hoping it would be available listed as distinct values in a table without having to use a reg_exp to extrapolate, but if this is the only other way then will accept as answer.
Thanks for the reply.